# forcing MKMapView to remove MKOverlayRenderer

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mapkit

I add custom  MKOverlayRenderer to MKMapView,Then I remove it with 
`removeOverlays()` but overlay stays there for a while, mkmapview updates the drawing, most of the time i move mkmapview region somewhere then back. is there a method to set that will force mkmapview render immediately?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same issue. I found online that

```
self.mapView.removeOverlays(self.mapView.overlays)
```

should remove them but it doesn't.

Turns out you have to create your MKPolylineRenderer or overlays as ivar.

```
var directionLineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer()

func remove() {
    if self.mapView.overlays.count != 0 {
        self.mapView.remove(self.directionLineRenderer.overlay)
    }
}
```